# open_port doesn't work when `exit_status` option not used

Tags: erlang

When I call open_port without `exit_status` in the example below it is unusable:

```
Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
1>  P = open_port({spawn, "cat >bar"}, [stream, use_stdio]).
#Port<0.498>
2> port_command(P, "hello\n").
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  port_command/2
        called as port_command(#Port<0.498>,"hello\n")
```

But when I just add `exit_status`  and leave everything the same it works:

```
Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
1> P = open_port({spawn, "cat >bar"}, [stream, use_stdio, exit_status]).
#Port<0.498>
2> port_command(P, "hello\n").
true
```

From the documentation I don't understand the difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you redirect output in a file in `cat >bar` command shell closes `stdout` and Erlang just closes the port in this case because ports try to consume command output by default and close on `eof`. The right way to fix it is to use `out` option as **butter71** already suggested. Options like `out`, `exit_status`, `error_to_stdout` tell ports to not bother about `stdout`.

Answer (score 4):

try setting the port for output only:

```
P = open_port({spawn, "cat >bar"}, [stream, use_stdio, out]).
port_command(P, "hello\n").
```

my guess is that erlang is unhappy because you redirected the command's stdout.