# How do you read from stdout of an external program in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, port

Here's the code I wrote:

```
-module(comments).

-record(comment, {user, contents, id, path, sub_comments}).
-export([sort_comments/1]).

comments2csv(Port, []) -> Port ! {self(), close};
comments2csv(Port, [#comment{user=User, contents=Contents, id=ID, path=Path}|Rest]) when is_integer(User) -> 
    Port ! {self(), {command, list_to_binary(Path ++ ":" ++ integer_to_list(User) ++ ":" ++ integer_to_list(ID) ++ ":" ++ Contents ++ "\n")}},
    comments2csv(Port, Rest).


sort_comments(Comments) ->
    Comments2 = [#comment{user=1, contents="hello", id=1, path="/1/", sub_comments=[]}],
    Port = open_port({spawn_executable, "./comsort"}, [binary]),
    comments2csv(Port, Comments2),
    receive
        {Port, {data, Data}} ->
            io:format("~p~n", [Data]);
        {Port, closed} ->
            io:format("closed~n"),
            receive
                X ->
                    io:format("~p~n", [X])
            end
    end.
```

It calls up an external program written in Haskell, and when I run it from the shell it prints "closed" and then hangs. I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not reading the output from the stdout of the program. The Haskell program is set up to print XML data to stdout when it's done receiving CSV data from stdin, and then it exits.

I loosely based it off of the tutorial [here:](https://www.erlang.org/docs/17/tutorial/c_port.html)

Comment: The hang part could be because... after printing "closed", the process runs into a `receive` after which it will wait for a message to arrive to process further.

Comment: And it could be the shell process itself waiting. Would you also like to tell us, how are you executing this `sort_comments`? Are you invoking it like `comments:sort_comments(...)` from the shell/terminal process directly ?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling up "comments:sort_comments([])." from the shell. I thought the receive part after printing "closed" would receive what was printed to stdout, or that it would receive that before the connection closed, but it doesn't seem to be receiving stdout at all.

Comment: Consider converting the program into a general unix filter with `escript`, then simply pipe the Haskell output into the escript tool.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550206/open-port-doesnt-work-when-exit-status-option-not-used) which has the options that I need to give to open_port in order to receive stuff from stdout. Now it works.

Edit: Nevermind. It seems that what I'm trying to do is impossible. Erlang doesn't let you close the file descriptor for stdin to a program called externally so comsort can't ever gather up all of the input and then send out the xml at the end because it never sees an end to the input.